# Use a clientId without a client secret

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-appsync

In AppSync when I try to Login via Cognito User Pools and enters ClientID it gives an error Use a clientId without a client secret.

I am entering only ClientID but it not proceeding

[image]

Comment: The app client for your user pool is probably configured with a client secret. However AppSync seems to require an app client without client secret.

Comment: @Dunedan where i can find that?

Comment: You can check your client configuration on the user pool to see if it requires a client secret. @Dunedan is correct, AppSync supports only clients without a client secret.

Answer (score 8):

1. Go to your user pool in the console.
2. Go to General Settings -> App Clients (NOT App Integration -> App client settings)
3. Click on "Show details" under each one.
4. Look at the "App client secret" field.

In my case Amplify had created two app clients for me, one with `_app_client` at the end, which had a client secret. One with `_app_clientWeb` at the end which had no client secret. They appeared to be otherwise identical. You want to select the App Client id from the one without the secret, or create a new app client that has no secret.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, it seems that AppSync doesnt allow using a user pool that has a client secret, so i created new user pool and I unchecked the generate client secret option while creating the App Client. Now it is working well.

Comment: This led me to my solution. Creating a new app client didn't work but by using the original app client without a secret and adding localhost to the sign in/out URL's fixed the issue for me.